# Difference between classical EM scattering an quantum EM scattering

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics

I am trying to reconcile the differences between classical scattering of EM radiation and quantum scattering of EM radiation.  Specifically for a metal or PEC (Perfect electric conductor), but insight into dielectrics would also be appreciated.

In the classical eletrodynamics viewpoint, the incident wave induces surface currents, and these currents radiate waves which are termed the scattering waves.

In the quantum electrodynamics viewpoint, the incident photon excites an electron to a higher energy state (based on the band structure characteristics of that material) and the electron subsequently falls back to the ground state via spontaneous emission and emits a photon (a "scattered" photon).

I argue that these are two **different** scattering mechanisms, although **there most certainly is overlap between the two in the classical case.**  I say this because scattered waves in the classical theory are caused by **moving** electrons in the form of currents (complex vector quantities), not due to excitations to higher energy levels.

What do you guys think??? Very eager to hear other viewpoints on this matter.

Comment: What is a PEC?  (Better to define potentially unfamiliar acronyms.)

Comment: Just edited.  PEC means perfect electric conductor.

Comment: Free electrons can be treated as plasmons. A quantum-mechanical Drude theory is a bit of a problem. A semiclassical theory for scattering by bound electrons is much simpler: Lorentz oscillators.